# Inject bean dynamically? Or @Autowire bean not created by Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, javabeans, autowired

Problem: **orderRepository** = **null**.
As I understand orderRepository not injected because **user** not the bean created by Spring but just an object created using **new** and then got its properties set in dao?

I'm making user as active object so injecting repository to model class. Any solution, or maybe there is better way?

```
@Controller
class UserController {
    ...
        // Get user from DB
        User user = userService.findUser(userId);
        Order order = user.findOrder(orderId);
    ...
}

@Component  
User {  
    @Autowired  
    OrderRepository orderRepository;

    Order findOrder(long orderId) {
        Order order = orderRepository
                .findOrderOrThrowException(this.getId(), orderId);
        return order;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the component-scan directive activated in your applicationContext.xml? <context:component-scan base-package="com.your.sourcefiles" />. How does the OrderRepository class look like?

Comment: Yes I got it all and app is bigger then what's above:) and works fine with injected repo into model, unless when I retrieve model class from DB. And this **User**  bean is created as new User() in dao, then properties are populated from result set. Repo class is regular class, has dao autowired to it.

Answer (score 0):

`User` is created by some repository, I guess. So you have to inject an `OrderRepository` yourself. Maybe your ORM / DB framework supports Interceptors, then you can have a central place where you inject the `OrderRepository`. Or even let Spring create an empty instance with the injected `OrderRepository` and the framework fill it with the values from the DB.

For the instances of `User` that are not created by a repository Spring would do the job.

Or you just make `orderRepository` a static member, which makes more sense imho.